On average when is it a good idea to reopen a question?
         in average? on average?
Does the community think it a good idea to reopen a ten-year-old question for the following reasons?

It has been viewed 152k times which tells us the dilemma of choosing  which preposition, "in" or "on", with average is a real one faced by anglophone speakers and learners.

Since its closure, the question has attracted 12 upvotes. Twelve upvotes that were cast after the question was closed.  Visitors found both the question and answer, which advocates in favour of "on average", to be useful and correct.

There is an online article (posted March 28, 2024) by Marcus Froland who claims:


The excerpts below is a fair representation of the author's answer  [emphasis not mine]
“In Average” or “On Average”? Correct Version Revealed


Many English learners wonder if they should say “in average” or “on average.” The correct phrase is “on average.”
By examining historical prevalence, modern dictionaries, and expert consensus, it becomes evident that “on average” is the valid construction in contemporary language.
There was a time when “in average” was commonly used, but it has gradually lost favor among native speakers and language professionals. Today, “on average” is the established norm, and the usage of “in average” is considered a common mistake. Some reasons behind the shift in popularity include the natural evolution of language and a greater emphasis on prepositional accuracy in modern English education.
As we’ve established, the phrase “on average” is now widely recognized as the proper expression, replacing the now-obsolete “in average.” This is an example of how language evolves over time and adapts to changing usage patterns.


Nothing at all was established, Froland only postulates without facts and "in average" is not obsolete in the slightest.


To demonstrate the importance of precision, let’s consider a real-world example. In a news report discussing economic issues, using “in average” instead of “on average” might lead to confusion among readers and misconstrue the intended meaning. Adhering to correct English usage ensures that the information is conveyed as intended, and your audience comprehends your message accurately.


But Froland offers no real-world examples, and completely fails to explain what kind of ambiguity using "in average" would create.


One of the most effective ways to sidestep common language errors is to familiarize yourself with correct usage and implement it in your everyday communication. In this case, historically outdated phrases like “in average” should be avoided in favor of the modern and correct “on average.”


Finally at the end of the article, Mr. Froland provides the statistics that support his argument. The number of results yielded by The New York Times search field.

An analysis of online language patterns, such as that found on The New York Times, evidences the prominent prevalence of “on average” over “in average”. This underscores the shift in language usage and the importance of adapting to modern English expressions for clear and effective communication.
   1. Use of “on average” in The New York Times: 35,000 instances
   2. Use of “in average” in The New York Times: 3,230 instances
As the data above illustrates, search engine trends reveal a clear preference for on average over in average, signifying its acceptance as the proper phrase in contemporary language usage.


The last reason why it might be a good idea to reopen the post:

All of the above will soon be assimilated by AI machines and anyone searching for an answer will probably be met with a ubiquitous and unanimous reply that "on average" is the most accurate, precise and only valid choice.
I am sure someone, more expert than me, can give a fuller more accurate and nuanced answer.

Do you think the closed EL&U question should be reopened? Alternatively, I wouldn't object to posting this (with some tweaking) as a question in its own right.

Any one of the three reasons you list could by itself provide a sufficient ground for reopening. In fact, I believe that closing a question improves this site only when it is a step towards its deletion. Leaving a closed question with posted answers on the site has the consequence of immunising the posted answers from competition and that is at odds with the fundamental idea behind the site's architecture, that the best answer will emerge though competition.

Do I cast a reopen vote?

Do I post this question on the main site?

Yes, you should cast a re-open vote on the Main question: that will put it into the review queue. No, you should not post this question on the Main site, because it's a Meta question. If the question is re-opened you can post an answer.

@AndrewLeach When I say this question, I meant after it has been modified it to make it on-topic. Was hoping to see someone casting their vote to reopen, not seen any so far.

Oh: sorry; Asperger's makes things literal. If you posted the question with an answer, fine; but you're posting a duplicate, which causes a problem -- which gets closed as a duplicate question? Better (I think!) to wait a bit -- maybe even a week -- for re-opening and only then post the answer. It was closed in 2013: what's another week?

I don't have a definite answer. It's implied in the Meta post.I am sure someone, more expert than me, can give a fuller more accurate and nuanced answer

The question has now been reopened. When faced with a question of such large and continuing interest across the internet, I don't think we do ourselves any favors by preventing site participants from submitting new answers to it (which is the main thing that closing an active question of significant interest accomplishes). Thanks for posting this Meta question and for researching and detailing some of the EL&U-worthy issues associated with it, Mari-Lou A!

@Mari-LouA, was the point of this meta-question merely to advocate the reopening of this particular question (which has now been accomplished), or to initiate a general discussion about reopening such questions? The title and the first sentence of the meta-question suggest the latter, but the rest of it suggests the former.

@jsw29  The title is ambiguous, but for the rest the aim was clear. The question's been opened and nobody has said I should post a new one. On the other hand, I'm pretty certain many 12-year-old questions have been recently closed unfairly because they don't conform to today's standard, so if you want to post an answer addressing that issue.

Who is Marcus Froland and why should we care what he says? This question seems more concerned with attacking him (maybe fairly but still off-topic), than discussing how the site works. Do we need any of that?

@StuartF  There are many "English learning" websites that give "rules" and explanations which are of a  low standard, nearly always superficial and sometimes even down right wrong.  If as a site we can provide learners and enthusiasts information about the English language that is more comprehensive and more accurate wouldn't that be on-topic and making the Internet a better place?

@StuartF I think "attacking" is a bit — no, rather a lot — overstating things. At worst the question here includes a rather lengthy digression into debate with the arguments made in a recent post by Froland (whoever he is and we're not really asked to care), Hardly an attack. Certainly somewhat off-topic for the meta question, except that it does help to establish both interest in, and topicality of, the then-closed question. As well as the potential for productive further contributions on that topic if answers were permitted. (Before it was reopened.)

On average, it's best to reopen a question on a Tuesday.

How can we know that "in average" is not followed by something? Like: in average readings or circumstances. We can't and that's the real rub here.
